# MongoCompass query a GUID

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

I am having issues figuring out how to properly query a GUID in my mongo compass as it is saved as a Binary type even though reading the docs it says that the mongo UI should show GUIDS as a type of UUID in the UI.

I did take a look at a lot of SO posts, but none seem to really assist in finding a correct way to write a query such that it will return the correct data point. For example:

My GUID is "387e07a2-4b48-481a-8403-7207c867c5ea", but the UI shows it as `_id: Binary('87Zil4J89k6XXEcbDbrlEA==', 3)`. What I need is a way of being able to write a query like `{ _id: UUID('myID') }` or some sort of conversion.

The C# driver of course handles converting GUIDs to and from flawlessly, this is mainly asking about how to do it within the MongoDB Compass.

EDIT: I know that if in my code I force the serializer to use strings for GUID as so:

`BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(new GuidSerializer(BsonType.String));` that it will show it accordingly, but this feels very heavy handed.

Comment: What does compass documentation say about this?

Comment: Wasn't able to really find it unless I wasn't searching correctly. I did see docs say that newer versions of compass should store GUIDs as UUID, but that is still not the case given that it is still binary. I've tried adding a conventionpack to my mongo on startup, but I am either stupid or something but the convention pack does absolutely nothing

Comment: What is the most relevant documentation you have located?

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/mongodb-compass-is-becoming-more-open-than-ever then i tried using this article: https://kevsoft.net/2020/06/25/storing-guids-as-strings-in-mongodb-with-csharp.html the setting of the serializer globally is fine, but causes issue on calling my api a second time as it says it has already been set. The convention appears to do nothing

Comment: That page specifies the syntax to use, what is then your question?

Comment: That it is still saved as Binary instead of UUID and therefore I cannot query it using UUID("My Guid Here")

Comment: UUID is a subtype of binary. What does "cannot query" mean?

Comment: I.e, if I do {id: UUID(<my guid>)} it returns nothing because the id expects me to query it using Binary. I would want it to be stored and displayed as UUID as it is shown in that article.

Comment: So you are saving as the wrong type. Save as uuid which is binary subtype 4. Subtype 3 is legacy uuid of which there are 3 different versions.

Comment: Okay, how do I set it as that type? My model is literally just public Guid InventoryId and I set is as the key using reflection since I don't want my domain project do have any visibility as to what ORM it uses

Comment: That depends on the driver you are using and should be described in its documentation.